# why this line works with parentheses around (t[i] = getche) != '\r', but doesn't work without?

Tags: arrays, c

this line should get input from the user and stop when he presses enter.
here is the line:

for (i = 0; (t[i] = getche()) != '\r'; i++); //works

for (i = 0; t[i] = getche() != '\r'; i++); //t is getting gibberish values

Comment: Look up operator precedence.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of operations. `!=` is higher precedence than `=`. Without parentheses, you get the character, compare it to `'\r'`, and assign either `1` or `0` to `t[i]` depending on the result of the comparison, rather than assigning the character read as intended (and as you do correctly with the parenthesized version).

Comment: Thank you. Pro answer, straight to the pointer.